# Wordpress Plugin Development

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this website http://wpbits.wordpress.com/2007/08/15/adding-options-to-wordpress-plugins/,to help me workout how to make a plugin that saves options.
Here is my code, but it wont seem to work. Can anyone point me in right direction please:

```
<?php 
/*
 * Plugin Name: test
 * Plugin URI: www.test.com
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: J Davies
 * Author URI: test.com
 * Description: Random Test
 */

function say_test(){
    $greeting = get_option('test_greeting');
    print "Say ".$greeting;
}

function set_test_options(){
    add_option('test_greeting','test','test');
}

function unset_test_options(){
    delete_option('test_greeting');
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'set_test_options');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__,'unset_test_options');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem, I needed to wrap each function in if(function_exists()).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only strange thing I can see here is that `add_option()` should only take two or four arguments (with an empty third). Setting the third causes Wordpress to run its `_deprecated_argument()` function which will trigger an error if in debug mode.